# How to get the value of 1st row "Name" from partial view when page first loads in parent view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to get the value of 1st row `Name` from partial view when page first loads in parent view. Please suggest me the way.

Model

```
public class ClsA
{        
    public List<first> firsts{ get; set; }    
    public List<second> seconds{ get; set; }
}

public class first
{     
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

}

public class second
{
    public string Details{ get; set; }
    public string Age{ get; set; }             
}
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult ABC()
 {
   string name="abc";// currently I am passing value manually
   SDetails sDetails=new SDetails();        
   var model = new ClsA();
   model.firsts = sDetails.Rst();            
   model.seconds = sDetails.Rs(name);   //I want to pass name value from 1st row of table        
   return View(model);
 }
```

View

```
  @model Aplication.Models.ABC.ClsA 

      @{ Html.RenderPartial("_Partial", Model.firsts); }
      @{ Html.RenderPartial("_PartialB", Model.seconds);}
```

PartialA

```
@model  IEnumerable<Aplication.Models.ABC.first>

    <table>
        <tr>
           <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Name)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Address)</th>            
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>                   
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)                    
                </td>                

            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

_PartialB

```
@model  IEnumerable<Aplication.Models.ABC.second>

    <table>
        <tr>
           <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Details)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Age)</th>            
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Details)
                </td>
                <td>                   
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)                    
                </td>                

            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking, but I'm guessing you want `string name = sDetails.Rst().FirstOrDefault().Name;`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Solved. Thank you. If possible then can you put the answer.

Comment: Someone already has :) - but just be aware that code would throw an exception if `sDetails.Rst()` contained an empty collection

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thank you for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code in view if you want statically first row from first partial view `Model.firsts().FirstOrDefault().Name`